# Quantum dissipation when coupling a system with a heat bath

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, hamiltonian-formalism, dissipation

In quantum mechanics, a good way to model dissipation of energy is to couple your system with a heat bath. This heath bath can be represented by a chain of harmonic oscillators. The Hamiltonian of the coupled system can be written as:
\begin{equation}
H = H_s + H_b + H_{int}.
\end{equation}
where $H_s$ is our system of interest, $H_b$ is the heat bath and we add an interaction term. Their expression is given by:
\begin{align}
H_s &= \frac{p^2}{2M} + V(q)\\
H_b &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{p_i^2}{2m} +\frac{k}{2}(x_i-x_{i+1})^2\\
H_{int}&= -kq\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i + N\frac{k}{2}q^2
\end{align}
If we consider the first system to be in certain excited state at time $t=0$, say $|n\rangle$, where $H_s|{n}\rangle = \varepsilon_n|n\rangle$. Can we say anything about the energy flux to the second system in the classical limit?

As an example, $H_s$ could be regarded as a Schwarzschild Black Hole of area (of the event Horizon) $A = 16\pi M$ (In this case $V(q)= \sqrt{ln(q)}$ is a good approximation). Therefore when coupled with the heat bath it should start radiating energy and therefore an energy flux will be, from $H_s$ to $H_b$.

Comment: Could you be more specific regarding your question? E.g. do you *want* a model that shows dissipation? What kind of behavior would you expect for the q.mech. case and for the classical case? Also, what kind of term is the -kq*sum(...) part, how did you come up with that?

Comment: So I want to compute the energy flux from the system s to the heat bath. k is nothing else than a  coupling constant. I took the interaction term from eq (4.4) from https://www.physik.uni-augsburg.de/theo1/hanggi/Chapter_4.pdf (found it on google).

Comment: Is this not exactly what is done in the origibal Caldeia-Leggett paper where the relate the friction to the spectral density of the heat bath. This is also in the text you cite in your comment. Once you have the friction you have the rate of energy transfer,

Comment: so then you would find the energy transfer by computing the work of the friction force? Is the friction force in this case the fluctuation force + the part proportional to the damping coefficient? (I am referring to equation 4.10 in the text I mentioned).